# RDB + GDB use case in AgensGraph

Tags: data-modeling, data-migration, agens-graph

Is there any person to let me know RDB + GDB use case?
I'm looking for some use cases by using AgensGraph which is multi-model database based on RDB + GDB.

Furthermore, also need to know how to migrate data from RDB to GDB, because data models between two databases are not same, do I have any tool to migrate partially automatically?

Answer (score 1):

**RDB + GDB AgensGraph Use Case:**
One of the AgensGraph use cases for RDB+GDB is having network topology in a graph format(As a Graph Layer) and then having  log data (ex. from IoT devices) which are time-series in relational tables.

**Data from RDB to GDB:**
You can use FDW extension or pg_dump(PostgreSQL) to migrate data from RDB to AgensGraph and the then model it in Graph.